# MySQL get the SUM of different currencies

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

In a MySQL database To get the SUM of a column I just do:

```
SELECT SUM(orderamount_total) FROM io__order_infos_hext
```

Is it possible in only one SQL request to get the SUM of `orderamount_total` of the different curriences defined in the column `currency`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need  a group by

```
SELECT currency, SUM(orderamount_total) 
FROM io__order_infos_hext
group by currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible. Please use the GROUP BY select clause.

```
SELECT SUM(orderamount_total) FROM io__order_infos_hext GROUP BY your_currency_column;
```